# How to add internal users posts sharing in a wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, sharing

I want to add internal posts sharing option in my website where users will be able to share each other posts with in the website.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is "Related Posts" and "Social" plugin. Look them in the plugin store.